# identify and mark duplicate rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify and mark duplicate rows based on 2 columns. I would like to make a unique identifier for each duplicate so I know not just that the row is a duplicate, but which row it is a duplicate with. 
I have a dataframe that looks like below with some duplicate item pairs (on fit and sit) and other pairs that are not duplicated. While the item pairs are duplicated, the information they contain is unique  (e.g., one row will have a value in Value1 for 1 row, but not Value2 and Value 3, the second or 'duplicate' row will have numbers for Value2 and Value3 just not Value1)

## current dataframe

```
     value1 value2 value3 fit   sit  
[1,] "1"    NA     NA     "it1" "it2"
[2,] NA     "3"    "2"    "it2" "it1"
[3,] "2"    "3"    "4"    "it3" "it4"
[4,] NA     NA     NA     "it4" "it3"
[5,] "5"    NA     NA     "it5" "it6"
[6,] NA     NA     "2"    "it6" "it5"
[7,] NA     "4"    NA     "it7" "it9"
```

code to generate example dataframe

```
value1<-c(1,NA,2,NA,5,NA,NA)
value2<-c(NA,3,3,NA,NA,NA, 4)
value3<-c(NA,2,4,NA,NA,2, NA)
fit<-c("it1","it2","it3","it4", "it5", "it6","it7")
sit<-c("it2","it1","it4","it3", "it6", "it5", "it9")
df.now<-cbind(value1,value2,value3, fit, sit)
```

what I want is to convert it to a dataframe that looks like this:

## desired dataframe

```
     val1 val2 val3 it1   it2  
[1,] "1"  "3"  "2"  "it1" "it2"
[2,] "2"  "3"  "4"  "it3" "it4"
[3,] "5"  NA   "2"  "it5" "it6"
[4,] NA   "4"  NA   "it7" "it9"
```

I was thinking of doing the following steps: 
1. create new variables using fit and sit with the lowest item  and highest items to identify duplicate pairs
2. identify duplicated item pairs
3. use ifelse to select and fill in unique information.

I know how to do steps 1 and 3, but am stuck on step 2. I think what I need to do is not just identify TRUE/FALSE duplicate, but perhaps have a column with a unique identifier for each item pair like this
(there are 2 extra rows because of my step 1):

```
     value1 value2 value3 fit   sit   lit   hit    dup
[1,] "1"    NA     NA     "it1" "it2" "it1" "it2"   1
[2,] NA     "3"    "2"    "it2" "it1" "it1" "it2"   1
[3,] "2"    "3"    "4"    "it3" "it4" "it3" "it4"   2
[4,] NA     NA     NA     "it4" "it3" "it3" "it4"   2
[5,] "5"    NA     NA     "it5" "it6" "it5" "it6"   3
[6,] NA     NA     "2"    "it6" "it5" "it5" "it6"   3
[7,] NA     "4"    NA     "it7" "it9" "it7" "it9"   NA
```

I am not sure how to do this.

What I am asking for is either help with step 2 or perhaps there is a better way to solve it than the steps I outlined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df.now %>%
 group_by(pair = paste(pmax(fit, sit), pmin(fit, sit), sep = "_")) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(starts_with("value")), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), 
                                                   NA,
                                                   first(na.omit(.))))

  pair    value1 value2 value3
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 it2_it1      1      3      2
2 it4_it3      2      3      4
3 it6_it5      5     NA      2
4 it9_it7     NA      4     NA
```

And if you also need the pairs in individual columns, then with the addition of `tidyr` you can do:

```
df.now %>%
 group_by(pair = paste(pmax(fit, sit), pmin(fit, sit), sep = "_")) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(starts_with("value")), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(.)), 
                                                   NA,
                                                   first(na.omit(.)))) %>%
 separate(pair, into = c("fit", "hit"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE)

  pair    fit   hit   value1 value2 value3
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 it2_it1 it2   it1        1      3      2
2 it4_it3 it4   it3        2      3      4
3 it6_it5 it6   it5        5     NA      2
4 it9_it7 it9   it7       NA      4     NA
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I appreciate adding in the option to separate the items.

Answer (score 3):

Use `!duplicated()` after `sort`ing.

```
df.now[!duplicated(t(apply(df.now[, c("fit", "sit")], 1, sort))), ]
#       value1 value2 value3 fit   sit  
# [1,] "1"    NA     NA     "it1" "it2"
# [2,] "2"    "3"    "4"    "it3" "it4"
# [3,] "5"    NA     NA     "it5" "it6"
# [4,] NA     "4"    NA     "it7" "it9"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, this solution deletes information I need to keep. I want to combine the information from the 3 value columns that are found across the 2 rows of the same item pairs. Let me know if this is not clear

Answer (score 2):

Using `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df.now)[, c('fit1', 'sit1') := .(pmin(fit, sit), 
    pmax(fit, sit))], measure = patterns("^value"), na.rm = TRUE),
     fit1 + sit1 ~ variable, value.var = 'value')
#   fit1 sit1 value1 value2 value3
#1:  it1  it2      1      3      2
#2:  it3  it4      2      3      4
#3:  it5  it6      5     NA      2
#4:  it7  it9     NA      4     NA
```

#### data

```
df.now <- data.frame(value1,value2,value3, fit, sit, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df.now)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) first(x[!is.na(x)])), 
    .(it1=pmin(fit, sit), it2=pmax(fit, sit)), 
    .SDcols=value1:value3]
```

output:

```
   it1 it2 value1 value2 value3
1: it1 it2      1      3      2
2: it3 it4      2      3      4
3: it5 it6      5   <NA>      2
4: it7 it9   <NA>      4   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt using data.table. Your data is called `mydf`. First, I sorted `fit` and `sit` for each row and created a new variable, `group`. Then, for each group, I sorted values in the three value columns (i.e., value1, value2, and value3). Finally, I extracted first row for each group.

```
library(data.table)

mydt <- setDT(mydf)[, group := paste(sort(.SD), collapse = "_"),
                    .SD = c("fit", "sit"), by = 1:nrow(mydf)][,
                        c("value1", "value2", "value3") := lapply(.SD, sort),
                        .SDcols = value1:value3, by = group][, .SD[1], by = group]

mydt[]

#     group value1 value2 value3 fit sit
#1: it1_it2      1      3      2 it1 it2
#2: it3_it4      2      3      4 it3 it4
#3: it5_it6      5     NA      2 it5 it6
#4: it7_it9     NA      4     NA it7 it9
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(value1 = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, NA), value2 = c(NA, 
3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L), value3 = c(NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA
), fit = c("it1", "it2", "it3", "it4", "it5", "it6", "it7"), 
sit = c("it2", "it1", "it4", "it3", "it6", "it5", "it9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer` with `values_drop_na = TRUE` combined with `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>%
   mutate(it1 = pmin(fit, sit), it2 = pmax(fit, sit)) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("value"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c("it1", "it2"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   it1   it2   value1 value2 value3
#>   <chr> <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 it1   it2        1      3      2
#> 2 it3   it4        2      3      4
#> 3 it5   it6        5     NA      2
#> 4 it7   it9       NA      4     NA
```

**Data**

```
mydf <- structure(list(value1 = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, NA), value2 = c(NA, 
3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 4L), value3 = c(NA, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA
), fit = c("it1", "it2", "it3", "it4", "it5", "it6", "it7"), 
sit = c("it2", "it1", "it4", "it3", "it6", "it5", "it9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```